# What does $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z)$ mean?

Tags: notation

In my course material I have the following notation
$$
\varphi \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z)
$$
where $Z⊂R^{n}$ is a bounded open set. I was wondering what does this notation mean? What is the set $\varphi$ belongs into? Please, help me :)

Comment: Is it really written with calligraphic C at both places?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z)$ is the set of infinitely differentiable functions defined on $Z$ with compact support, i.e. they are zero outside some compact set.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I've never seen it with a calligraphic C in either place. It's normally written $C_c^\infty(Z)$. But styles can vary.

Comment: @md2perpe I hadn't either, I'm only following the convention used by machniik.